# React callback binding error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in my quotes component:

```
componentWillMount(){
    QuoteStore.on("newQuoteAdded",this.getQuotes);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    QuoteStore.removeListener("newQuoteAdded",this.getQuotes);
}

getQuotes(){
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({
        quotes:QuoteStore.getQuotes()
    });
}
```

An event is emitted when new data is added to the flux store (QuoteStore) like this

```
addQuote(quote,author){
    const newQuote=new Object();
    const date=Date.now().toString();
    newQuote.id=date;
    newQuote.author=author;
    newQuote.quote=quote;

    this.Quotes.push(newQuote);
    this.emit("newQuoteAdded");
}
```

I am getting this error when my component actually captures this event :

**this.setState is not a function at QuoteStore.getQuotes**

Can anyone help, how can I bind my **this** to Quotes component in *getQuotes()* callback on event capturing?

Comment: add .bind(this) at the end of the method’s call